# Select data from mysql and if exist increment by one

Tags: php, mysql

So what i want is to insert username in table user, So what i want to do is something like this. On my example username will be Jhon. So i want to insert Jhon int table user in column username. And before i insert username i check if Jhon already exist in table. And if Jhon exist (i count rows to see if is already exist) then set John to John2 (because John exist i count 1 row and that count increment by one and add it to John so result is John2). All that works for me but problems start when in my table is John and John2. Then i can count only John and i will inserting John2 all the time. So my problem is how to count all John, John2, John3, John4... from table and get the rows count so when i count 3 Johns so php know there are 3 Johns and it need insert John4?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I recommend you check out [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on how to ask a good question. Please post what you've researched so far, or show us some code samples.

Comment: Forget about finding a solution to your current logic, you have to change your logic . If you see John, then inserting the count and appending the count and making as John 2 itself is bad

Comment: If you insist you need this logic only, an excerpt from @Barmar will help . You'll get the count from this query 'SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM user WHERE username REGEXP '^John[0-9]*$'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a subquery that counts the number of matching names. Add 1 to that and concatenate it to the prefix.

```
INSERT INTO user (username, col1, col2, col3)
SELECT CONCAT('Jhon', IF(count = 0, '', count+1)), col1value, col2value, col3value
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) as count
      FROM user
      WHERE username REGEXP '^Jhon[0-9]*$') AS x
```

Comment: thanks and what if i want to insert more data with in the same query?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to have more values.